# Logitech Z623 2.1 Speakers - constant crackling from left speaker

Tags: speakers, logitech-speakers

I just recently bought and set up the Logitech Z623 2.1 Speakers a few days ago, and I've just noticed a low-key, constant crackling noise coming from specifically and only from the *left* speaker whenever the speakers are turned on. It isn't affected by volume on the speakers or computer as far as I can tell, and it seems to continue while playing sound, though it doesn't seem usually noticeable at that point. I don't think it's been doing this since I set it up, though.

I unplugged the speaker's input entirely, and the crackling continued whenever the speakers were on regardless, so I get the feeling it's not a software issue.

Comment: Well, _every_ real-world amplifier produces some noise. Depending on the quality of circuit it's either higher or lower.

If it is unnoticeable, I would consider it normal, but if it's annoying, then consider unplugging any source of radio noise near your speakers, like PC, electronic lamps, mobile phone, Wi-Fi router, Bluetooth devices and check out if it helps.

Comment: If unplugged it still does it… Can you swap the physical speaker plugs over? Does the sound change to the new speaker? If so, just send it back, there's something wrong with the amp, which on a brand-new piece of gear, you don't even need to attempt to investigate.

Comment: IF you unplug the speakers from the PC and plug them into a TV, radio, or smartphone, does the problem persist? if so, it's a speaker hardware problem; try rearranging the cables so the signal cable is either at least a foot away from the power cable, or crosses the power cable at a right angle.

Comment: @K7AAY - I wouldn't equate 'cracking' with EMI from any mains source etc & if unplugged from any signal source continues… I'd be looking at caps, anything from motor-boating to poor solder job… As it's brand new I wouldn't even bother investigating further than "yup, it's at the amp"

Comment: The speakers cannot be swapped, the use entirely different plugs and the right speaker also has the controls. I did have a feeling it was a hardware issue, and I'm making a warranty claim.